# Help with a tricky matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Say I have the following variable length vectors containing unknown values:

$$
A=\left (\begin{array}{c}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
\vdots\\
a_i\\
\end{array}\right)
B=\left (\begin{array}{c}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
\vdots\\
b_j\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

And the following variable length vectors and matrix (according to the size of the preceding vectors) containing known values:

$$
A_T=\left (\begin{array}{c}
a'_1 \\
a'_2 \\
\vdots\\
a'_i\\
\end{array}\right)
B_T=\left (\begin{array}{c}
b'_1 \\
b'_2 \\
\vdots\\
b'_j\\
\end{array}\right)
K=\left (\begin{array}{ccc}
k_{11} & \cdots & k_{1j} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k_{i1} & \cdots & k_{ij}\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

These are all related by the following two equations:
$$
A_T = A + diag(A)KB\\
B_T = B + diag(B)K^TA
$$

Given all of the known values, I want to know if it is possible to solve for A and B. If so how should I go about figuring this out? I only have a basic education on matrix math.

Comment: My bad, I edited it. The values are different, just the same length.

Comment: This looks pretty weird to me. In any case the equation are not linear in $A,B$, due to the _diag_ factors. So standard linear algebra methods do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc writes, the problem is not a linear one. Yet, I did numerical tests and the results are surprising. Of course, we work with generic systems. When $i=j=3$ or $4$, the associated system of algebraic equations decompose in linear subsystems; that is, the solutions $(a_k),(b_k)$ are rational functions of the $(k_{*,*}),(a'_{*}),(b'_{*})$. Moreover, there is only a finite number of solutions in $(A,B)$; more precisely, $20$ solutions for $i=j=3$ and $70$ solutions for $i=j=4$.